# Very long useragent

Tags: http-headers, useragent

We have requests in our server log with a very long useragent:

```
HEADER: user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873; WUID=4bddaa48430e60af6132822cd6fab6c4; WTB=2873) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
```

We log useragents in a database table, but this useragent exceeds the field's string length.

Can anyone explain why this user has such a long useragent? What does the WUID etc. mean?

The user told he's using Firefox 41.0.1. on Windows 7

Comment: According to https://twitter.com/JoeBeOne/status/418704522249519105 it could be an Opera thing. List of installed extensions.

Comment: but the user was using FF not opera

Comment: Users can lie or be mistaken. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1070924#answer-750470 seems to indicate it might be a similar thing in FF - an extension that changed the user agent.

Comment: That UA _claims_ to be Firefox 32. The user probably has some serious installation problem with his browser. Oh, and your database field is too short.